# How to set SearchBar text field text

Tags: ios

I am setting UISearchController as following

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

In results UIViewController, I need to set search text when button clicked

this code doesn't work

```
navigationController?.navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.searchTextField.text = searchText
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a reference of your `searchController` as a property. For example, you have a property:

```
  lazy var searchController: UISearchController = {
      let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
      searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
      searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = .white
      return searchController
  }()
```

and then assigning that property to navigationItem like what you did:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
  }
```

and then finally, setting search text when a button is clicked:

```
self.searchController.searchBar.text = "✅"
```

---

OR SIMPLY:

```
self.navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.text = "✅"
```

No need to get these from your `navigationController`.